# error sql (1064): you have an error in your SQL syntax''

Tags: mysql, mariadb, heidisql

I want run this query but get an error:

error sql (1064): you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server Version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 97

My Query is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ControlRecibos` ()
BEGIN
    Select distinct T0.gestionescobra_tks_regional
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_cobrador
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_codigodecli
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_apellidoyno
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_formadepago
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_observacion
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_fechareport
    ,T0.gestionescobra_tks_montoprima
    ,T1.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprimama
    ,T1.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima
    From vtiger_gestionescobra T0 inner join 
    (   Select *
            From(
                    Select distinct gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza,sum(gestionescobra_tks_montoprima) as MonCobrado
                            From vtiger_gestionescobra 
                        where gestionescobra_tks_fechareport between '2020-03-20' and '2020-04-20' and
                        gestionescobra_tks_actividad = 'Cobranza' and gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib <>'' and   gestionescobra_tks_notransacci <>'' and gestionescobra_tks_montoprima <> 0 and gestionescobra_tks_formadepago='M'   group by gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza  )T0 inner Join  (Select T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprimama,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes T0 inner join (
                        Select distinct nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,max(nocobradosmesid) as val
                            From vtiger_nocobradosmes
                            group by nocobradosmes_tks_poliza)

            T1 ON T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza
            where T0.nocobradosmesid=T1.val and nocobradosmes_tks_formadepago='Mensual') 
            T1 ON T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza 
            where (nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima*50)/100>MonCobrado
    Union
            Select *
            From(Select gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza,sum(gestionescobra_tks_montoprima) as MonCobrado
            From vtiger_gestionescobra 
            where gestionescobra_tks_fechareport between  '2020-03-20' and '2020-04-20' and
            gestionescobra_tks_actividad = 'Cobranza' and gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib <>'' and 
            gestionescobra_tks_notransacci <>'' and gestionescobra_tks_montoprima <> 0 and gestionescobra_tks_formadepago='T'
            group by gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza) 
            T0 inner Join 
            (Select T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprimama,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes T0 inner join (Select distinct nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,max(nocobradosmesid) as val
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes
            group by nocobradosmes_tks_poliza) T1 ON T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza
            where T0.nocobradosmesid=T1.val and nocobradosmes_tks_formadepago='Trimestral' ) 
            T1 ON T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza 
            where (nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima)/3>MonCobrado
    Union
            Select *
            From(Select gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza,sum(gestionescobra_tks_montoprima) as MonCobrado
            From vtiger_gestionescobra 
            where gestionescobra_tks_fechareport between '2020-03-20' and '2020-04-20' and
            gestionescobra_tks_actividad = 'Cobranza' and gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib <>'' and 
            gestionescobra_tks_notransacci <>'' and gestionescobra_tks_montoprima <> 0 and gestionescobra_tks_formadepago='S'
            group by gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza)
             T0 inner Join 
            (Select T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprimama,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes T0 inner join 
            (Select distinct nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,max(nocobradosmesid) as val
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes
            group by nocobradosmes_tks_poliza) T1 ON T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza
            where T0.nocobradosmesid=T1.val and nocobradosmes_tks_formadepago='Semestral') 
            T1 ON T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza 
            where (nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima)/6>MonCobrado
    Union
            Select *
            From(Select gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza,sum(gestionescobra_tks_montoprima) as MonCobrado
            From vtiger_gestionescobra
            where gestionescobra_tks_fechareport between '2020-03-20' and '2020-04-20'and
            gestionescobra_tks_actividad = 'Cobranza' and gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib <>'' and 
            gestionescobra_tks_notransacci <>'' and gestionescobra_tks_montoprima <> 0 and gestionescobra_tks_formadepago='A'
            group by gestionescobra_tks_cobrador,gestionescobra_tks_poliza) 
            T0 inner Join 
            (Select T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprimama,T0.nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima
            From vtiger_nocobradosmes 
            T0 inner join (
                            Select distinct nocobradosmes_tks_poliza,max(nocobradosmesid) as val
                                    From vtiger_nocobradosmes
                                    group by nocobradosmes_tks_poliza
                        ) T1 ON T0.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza
            where T0.nocobradosmesid=T1.val and nocobradosmes_tks_formadepago='Anual'
            )
             T1 ON T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza=T1.nocobradosmes_tks_poliza 
            where (nocobradosmes_tks_montoprima)/12>MonCobrado
    )
     T1 ON T0.gestionescobra_tks_cobrador=T1.gestionescobra_tks_cobrador 
     and T0.gestionescobra_tks_poliza=T1.gestionescobra_tks_poliza
    where gestionescobra_tks_fechareport between '2020-03-20' and '2020-04-20' and
    gestionescobra_tks_actividad = "Cobranza" 
    and gestionescobra_tks_numerorecib <>'' 
    and gestionescobra_tks_notransacci <>'' 
    and gestionescobra_tks_montoprima <> 0
    ORDER BY 1,2;
```

END

MYSQL WorkBench only show me the problem on 2 last lines, like "Missing SemiColon" in 2 and extraneous input found in END

What's the problem?

Comment: It is not easy to help as we have no knowledge of the database. However, what you should do it run the query directly in the MariaDB command prompt. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-sql-debugging/.
I will also section the query and load into workbench just the content of the unions to determine the problem easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [DELIMITER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) when you create stored procedures to be something else than the semicolon.